# strategies for loading data into a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a system where the user can select templates from a dropdown menu of up to 300 options.

When the user selects one, a readonly `textarea` is filled with a corresponding string of length <= 1000 characters.

When the page loads, should I:

- store them all in a JavaScript variable, and reference the variable on the `select` change?
- load the content via ajax when the select changes?

Comment: @p.campbell, apologies that my grammar skills are not that great at the moment. A week of 2 hour sleeps will do that to you! So thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to already know the answer: you can preload the templates into your HTML, but then the page becomes large and slow to download, with most of the templates never being used. If you use AJAX, only the minimum necessary information gets downloaded.

Comment: Im wondering in terms of requests, I guess I could implement some form of caching so that at most a templates contents is only requested once at most per page load. but, if the user is simply scrolling the list viewing all the content thats 300 extra requests to the server, and the list scrolling is something I commonly do myself...

Comment: Is having extra requests a real problem or a fictional potential problem?

Comment: could become a real problem, the system is expected to be a relatively high volume application and this is pretty much a central part.

Comment: If these templates are not customized to the individual user requesting them, then your caching layer (whether it's part of your application, or a proxy like Varnish sitting in front) is just serving static files in response to the request. A commodity box with properly configured services should be able to handle tens of thousands of requests for static content *per second*.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a function on click:

```
var infoArray = new Array();

$('item').click(function() {
    var itemName = $(this).attr('id');

    if(infoArray[itemName] !== undefined)
    {
        $('loader').empty().load('url', function() { 
            infoArray.push({itemName:$('loader').text()});
        });
    } else {
        $('loader').empty().append(infoArray[itemName]);
    }
});
```